# How can I configure traffic balancing for a service using Istio?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

We use a headless service to balance traffic, but progers do not like this option. Installed istio, I read the documentation, but my eyes run wide.

Now the task is:
Balance traffic to the service, in my case: `results-service2.predprod.svc.cluster.local`

Do I understand correctly that it is enough for me to create a `DestinationRule` and all incoming traffic to `results-service2.predprod.svc.cluster.local` will be balanced on replicas using the `LEAST_CONN` balancing algorithm?

In my case:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: results-load-balancer
spec:
  host: results-service2.predprod.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
      loadBalancer:
        simple: LEAST_CONN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Istio destination rule is place to define service load balancing algorithm.  By default istio uses "LEAST_REQUEST" as LB algorithm.  "LEAST_CONN" is deprecated algorithm.  More details are mentioned in [istio documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#LoadBalancerSettings-SimpleLB).  If you would like to change LB algorithm to "ROUND_ROBIN" or another supported methon this can be done as per below sample

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: configure-client-mtls-dr-with-workloadselector
spec:
  host: example.com
  workloadSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ratings
  trafficPolicy:
    loadBalancer:
      simple: ROUND_ROBIN
```